# How to pass an object param with $http POST and access in Nodejs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, http-post

I have created a POST request where i am sending a param to server and in the server side i am getting the error is like the data not found.

Client js

```
var postData= JSON.stringify({name:"Alex",age:"34"});
var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post(appSettings.baseUrl + '/users', postData)
                .success(function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response)
                }).error(function (error) {
                    deferred.reject('Failed to connect');
                });


            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Serverjs (Nodejs)

```
app.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.body.postData;
   // user is not getting in server
    });
});
```

I am not able to get the the postData in the server.

Comment: you using any `body-parser` ?

Comment: Yes @GeorgeBailey
I am using below line
`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50358943/6804958) answer ?

Comment: Yes @GeorgeBailey i have tried the last method you suggested and it worked. Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `postDate` property on the data sent in body with the request and you are not sending any object with `postData` property.

If you check in node backend logging `console.log(req.body)`, I am really sure that you're getting

```
{name:"Alex",age:"34"}
```

And you should access any property here like `req.body.name` or `req.body.age`

If you want to access the full object on body with any property name you better send it with a property name like

```
$http.post(appSettings.baseUrl + '/users', {"postData" : postData})
```

Comment: Thanks Geroge, it worked with `$http.post(appSettings.baseUrl + '/users', {"postData" : postData})` . Now i understand the correct usage of body-parser.